# mouseout set previus returns previous bg image of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseover, mouseout

all.
I have.

```
<div id="imagecontainer" class="header-image-container">&nbsp;</div>
```

BG image are specified in css for ich page according on parent class.

```
.category-1 #imagecontainer {
background: url(_/images/1.jpg);
}
```

And i have menu. I want to chage BG image ommouse over, and on mouse out return image specified in css for this page according on parent class. I think it could be real using JQuery. For example we have opened category-3 page and move mouse on category-1 menu item and see catefory-1 BG image in  #imagecontainer, and then we move mouse out see again category-3 BG image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do you want:

```
$('#menu').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#imagecontainer').css({'background':'blue'});
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#imagecontainer').removeAttr('style');
})
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cdzk8/

If you have other inline styles on your imagecontainer, it will also remove those on mouseleave. In that case, you will have do something more like what mblase75 is recommending.

Comment: Thanks. It works on my project =). but I'm really upset that I could not get to work method suggested by mblase75.

Answer (score 0):

Store the current background image as `data` before swapping it out, and retrieve it from there when you want to swap it back.

```
$('#imagecontainer').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).data('bgimg') = $(this).css('background-image');
    $(this).css('background-image','url(my/new/url.jpg)');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', $(this).data('bgimg'));
});
```

Comment: Are you using the same `#imagecontainer` ID on multiple items? That's not allowed, and could explain your problem.

Comment: i try your solution http://jsfiddle.net/S7xKn/3/ and nothig works... untill i delete second line of your script